# Showing Partial result from large volume of data

Tags: r, volume

I have downloaded 496 matrices containing 496 companies data. Each matrix have columns like this

```
          AAL.Open  AAL.High  AAL.Low  AAL.Close   AAL.Volume
09-12-13    23.85   25.44     23.45      24.6        43197268
10-12-13    24.5    25.17     24.41      24.88       18660625

           AA.Open  AA.High   AA.Low  AA.Close    AA.Volume
09-12-13    22.5     24.25    20.13      21           6639
10-12-13    21.2     21.2     20.89      21           10963
```

I use this formula to have a new metrix

```
df<- do.call(cbind, lapply(lst, function(x) x[,2]))
```

I successfully create another file like this

```
    AAL.High    AA.High   -----   ------
09-12-13    25.44     24.25
10-12-13    25.17      21.2
```

But the problem is the new file only produce around 70 columns instead of 496 columns. That means resutls are only on a small part of my total data.To get detail code you can use this link 
[R codes](http://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2qiwb7LSg7KTVdTWEZuVHc5WXM)

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, complete & verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) within the question itself? It's generally not good practice to link to a lot of external code. See discussion here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266909/should-a-question-that-is-meaningless-without-viewing-an-external-link-be-closed

Comment: ok. I will follow the instructions.

Comment: Since the problem is related with large volume, that is why I had to post the link. the code is working but working only upon some DF or matrices

Comment: What's the minimum number of matrices that trigger the problem? Does it always occur after a specific number of matrices? Does it matter whether you switch the order of matrices? Is it always the same matrices that get dropped? Are there common characteristics among the matrices that get dropped? I hope you see where I'm going with this. Try to isolate what's triggering your problem.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion.